# net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in socket.io connection

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, connection, connection-refused

I am trying to make a chat app, but when trying to establish the connection I get the following error in the frontend console.

```
polling-xhr.js:198 GET http://localhost:8900/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NjM8sny net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

The code in the frontend is the following:

```
        useEffect(() => {
    socket.current = io.connect("http://localhost:8900/");
    socket.current.on("getMessage", (data) => {
      setArrivalMessage({
        sender: data.senderId,
        text: data.text,
        createdAt: Date.now(),
      });
    });
}, []);
```

The code in the backend is:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(8900,{
cors: {
    origin:'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials:true,
    allowedHeaders: ["access-token"],
},
```

});

I would like to know if there is any error in my code or if I am missing some type of module.

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, this might be happening because the connection is not getting established between the socket-client and socket-server.

If your backend code is all that you've posted in the question, you've not added a connection socket in the backend. Including something similar to the below, might help.

```
 io.on('connection', (socket) => {
     console.log(socket.id, 'connected');
     // anything else you'd like to do here
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

On client side change your code like this by removing `io.connect`

```
const io = require("socket.io-client");
socket.current = io("http://localhost:8900/");
```

And then use `socket.current` to listening on events

`